# SQL, Applying two left join with condition in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables ss(id),aa(id,date) and bb(id,date) with more than 5000000 lines each, I want to left join those tables to get this resut:

- if aa.id == bb.id and aa.date==bb.date, and aa.id exists in the table ss, I want to join this data into the same line (first line in my example)
- if ss.id == aa.id and , aa.id doesn't exist in table bb or exist but with a different "date" than the aa.date, then I want to get only the related data to aa and ss (third line in my example)
- if ss.id == bb.id and , bb.id doesn't exist in table aa or exist but with a different "date" than the bb.date, then I want to get only the related data to bb and ss (second line in my example)

  ```
  ss.id     aa.id         aa.date        bb.id         bb.date
  1             1            2013            1            2013
  1                                          1            2014
  1             1            2012
  ```

In addition to this operation, I want also to sum some indicators that I have in those tables (other columns that i didn't mention above) and group them by ss.dd and Date, the query that I made give me the correct result, but it's executing in an inaxeptable long time (more than 30 minutes ) so I want your help to solve this, my query is something like this

```
select ss.id,aa.datee,sum(one_of_my_indicators) from ss

left join aa
on ss.id=aa.id

left  join bb
on (
ss.id=bb.id 
and bb.datee=aa.datee
and aa.id is not null
)
 or 
(
ss.id=bb.id 
and aa.id is null
)
group by ss.id,aa.datee;
```

PS: I have indexes on all significant columns in my query, such as the 'ss.id'
,aa and bb's 'date' and 'id'.
PS: I need a condition that select from the table 'ss' and then do other other joins, because my query is a very specific one and I have to use it with another tool (Galigeo).

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the query as this:

```
select ss.id, aa.datee,sum(one_of_my_indicators)
from ss left join
     aa
     on ss.id = aa.id left join
     bb
     on ss.id=bb.id and
      ((bb.datee=aa.datee and
         aa.id is not null
        ) or
        aa.id is null
       )
group by ss.id, aa.datee;
```

The Oracle optimizer may not be smart enough to figure out that the `join` condition is the same.

I keep thinking, though, that this is equivalent to:

```
select ss.id, aa.datee,sum(one_of_my_indicators)
from ss left join
     aa
     on ss.id = aa.id left join
     bb
     on ss.id = bb.id and
        bb.date = aa.date
group by ss.id, aa.datee;
```

Does this query work for what you are doing?

EDIT:

The way to fix this is with two queries and `union`:

```
select ss.id, aa.datee, sum(one_of_my_indicators)
from ss left join
     aa
     on ss.id = aa.id left join
     bb
     on ss.id=bb.id and
        bb.datee=aa.datee and
        aa.id is not null
group by ss.id, aa.datee;
union all
select ss.id, aa.datee,sum(one_of_my_indicators)
from ss left join
     aa
     on ss.id = aa.id left join
     bb
     on ss.id=bb.id and
        aa.id is null
group by ss.id, aa.datee;
```

I don't think you need to do an additional `group by` because the `aa.datee` should be `NULL` for the second query and have a value for the first.

Comment: Thank you Gordon for your help, your first query has the same problem as the mine, for the second one, not all my 'bb' data exit in the table 'aa' and vice versa, it's also the case between aa and ss and aa and bb, so using your second query will give a result in a better time but it doesn't give the correct one, we loose a lot of line records, I appreciate your response mister Gorden, thank you.